# MySqlCommand string variable argument not working

Tags: mysql, string

I am building a function to process a command, but MySQLCommand is not taking my string as an argument on the following code, could you please help me?

```
int executeCommand(const std::string & mySqlCommand)
{ 
    MySqlCommand ^ _cmdDataBased = gcnew MySqlCommand(mySqlCommand, _connDatabase);
    {
        try {
            _connDatabase->Open();
            _myReader = _cmdDataBase->ExecuteReader();    
            while (_myReader->Read()) {}
            return 1;
        }
        catch (Exception^ex) {
            //error management here please
            return 0;
        }
}
```

when I utilize "command" instead of the variable mySqlCommand, the error goes away, but I want to take the command from my function's argument. I've tried defining this variable in multiple times, System::String, char *, putting it as ("%s",mySqlCommand) etc, etc...

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

I need to use System::String^ type for the variable mySqlCommand. I am no expert, just learning and I just found out that since mySqlCommand is managed, the argument cannot be the native std::string, please correct me if I'm wrong.